# VisualVM "not supported for this JVM" on all local applications?

Tags: java, profiler, visualvm

I have already spent a long time to load and test my application, now I need to profile it. But unluckily, the VisualVM always says "not supported for this JVM" on my local applications?

The applications were started on the same JVM with VisualVM.

Comment: if you're on Linux, check your alternatives for the JVM and try launching with the full path of each application (full path for JVM + full path for VisualVM). Symbolic links may not point to the same directory

Comment: Sorry, I can't remember this. However, I see my own comment in the answer of Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen that "The root issue is my log in username, it is capitalized letters!".

Answer (score 23):

I found out that (at least under Windows) one can easily write small batch files to run VisualVM in combination with specific JVMs, which is important for me, since I have installed the 32bit JDK alongside with the 64bit JDK (I need both, so this is sensible for me).
I have created two batch files in the folder "S:\applications\visualvm\bin\":

run_32.bat:

```
@echo off
START "VisualVM 32" visualvm.exe --jdkhome "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_07"
```

run_64.bat:

```
@echo off
START "VisualVM 64" visualvm.exe --jdkhome "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_07"
```

Obviously, all paths may differ on your system, but the general idea should still work correctly (on all 64bit versions of Windows). The benefit is that I can use the 32bit batch file when I want to use VisualVM in combination with Java applications that run on the 32bit JVM, and so on for 64bit.

The "start" command has the only benefit that the batch file launches the application without waiting for it to finish, so the command prompt window closes immediately. This is not a feature of VisualVM, but of the Windows batch file interpreter.

Comment: Comment by @MSillence: Please note that the path must not contain a trailing "\" or it will deny that the path is a valid jdk home

Comment: What if the application and VisualVM are running through the exact same JVM?

Comment: Had the same problem on Ubuntu 18.08, this works for me (run in a terminal):

visualvm --jdkhome /usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_80/

Answer (score 14):

In my case, even with the JVMs matching (both 64-Bit), the only way to get things working was sending the argument `-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote` to the JVM to be monitored. That also works if you are having problems to connect via Java Mission Control (JMC).

According to [JMX's documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/management/agent.html), this what the argument does:

> Setting this property registered the Java VM platform's MBeans and published the Remote Method Invocation (RMI) connector via a private interface to allow JMX client applications to monitor a local Java platform, that is, a Java VM running on the same machine as the JMX client.

This was supposed to be enabled automatically, but for some reason it wasn't on my Linux.

Comment: Yes. for some reason I got the same so only JMX Connection works :( after I added `-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=12345 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false  -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false`

Answer (score 13):

VisualVM needs to be run with the same JVM - at least Java 6 with the same 32-bit/64-bit size - as the program to be profiled.  (You also need to be the same user, but then this message does not apply).

I would be triple-check that it was the exact same JVM in your situation.

Comment: I did remove all jdk/jre then install only one. but it still failed :-(

Comment: - winxp service pack2, jdk 1.6.0_17

Comment: Which JVM did you install?  Do you have a JVM installed through a browser plugin?  How do you start your application?

Comment: also jvm 1.6_17. They are all installed from the same package. The application is started by browser plugin, but I also tested with the other desktop applications. They are all failed. However, I can do profile on another PC.

Comment: There is a troubleshooting guide from the VisualVM team at http://visualvm.java.net/troubleshooting.html - you might be lucky.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It helps. Badly that I couldn't find it when searching by the keyword from the error message! The root issue is my log in username, it is capitalized letters!

Comment: Is this 'Local Java applications cannot be monitored' error message you have got? If so, VisualVM error dialog have html link pointing directly to the troubleshooting guide.

Comment: @Tomas, I was wondering what the underlying cause for 32-bit JVM's cannot attach to 64-bit and vice versa is?  Also, what is the reason for capitalized letters being a problem?

Comment: 32bit/64bit attach problem happens only on Windows. All other platforms works fine. This is problem of Attach API, one of the APIs VisualVM uses to monitor JVM. See the following JDK bug: http://bugs.sun.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=6277710

Comment: @TomasHurka link appears to have moved.

Comment: For me it was caused by a user difference between monitored process and the profiler - I got the exact message for CPU "Not supported by this CPU".

Answer (score 3):

On Linux: 
Make sure that your /etc/hosts correctly references the effective ip address of your "hostname"
It appears that a discrepancy here totally confuses the poor jvisualvm and its programmers.

Comment: This and setting and loading jvisualvm in this way did the work:
`$ jvisualvm --cp:a ~/luca4pro/wildfly-9.0.2.Final/bin/client/jboss-client.jar`

Answer (score 3):

I too got the same problem for local tomcat, I search for solutions for stackoverflow. after some serious debugging, I figured out that VisualGC don't have permissions to get GC informations from tool.jar file.

by links

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/share/jstatd.html#SECURITY
https://stackoverflow.com/a/42107355/3876619

I following steps to solve the issue

1) Create a permission file

```
vim /tmp/tools.policy
```

Add

```
grant codebase "file:${java.home}/../lib/tools.jar" {
   permission java.security.AllPermission;
};
```

save it

2) Now add /tmp/tools.policy to JVM startup parameters

```
-Djava.security.policy=/tmp/tools.policy
```

3) Run jvisualVm with sudo

Answer (score 2):

An issue that I just found, thanks to the hint from @user3356656, is that if you start the program while your machine is on one IP, and then try to connect while it is on a different IP, it will fail.

Comment: I also work around by 

1. turn off wifi 
2. start target process.
3. start visualvm. 
4. turn on wifi. 

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I also met this issue. My case is that on linux, I started tomcat with tomcat_user but I run jvisualvm with root user. It works after I start tomcat with root user.

Comment: This was also my problem. But it may be better to run visualvm as tomcat_user rather than running tomcat as root.

Answer (score 2):

I was having the problem having of visualvm detect my local tomcat installation on Windows 7. I could connect manually, but then things like memory snapshots and visualgc plugin were not enabled. I confirmed that I was using same JVM version, temp file permissions, etc. Didn't work. Then I found that starting visualvm first, and then tomcat, solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

As you can see, you are running VisualVM on 32bit JVM

You don't need to unistall 32bit JVM. Just tell VisualVM to use tour 64bit JVM.

If you want to change it permanently, you can edit

in **visualvm_13\etc\visualvm.conf** and specify the path of jvm here

Answer (score 1):

I can reproduce next behaviour.
I have a java application with right-click menu item to open jvisualvm.
I'm running this java application as standalone setup from a bat file.
It means I modify %path% and other needed environment variables like JDK 
accordingly to form my environment. 
The BAT that starts application is marked running as non-admin. Environment points to a 64-bit JDK. 
Then I start other java application as admin. VM lives from the to same 64-bit JDK-source.
Then I start jvisualvm from first app with the right click ie.as non-admin. 
I can see the app in jvisualvm ‘Applications list’ but clickin ‘System properties’ gives error. Message is  “Not supported for this JVM”.
JVM arguments are exposed.

Solution is like in some other previous comments:
Starting  my right-click jvisualvm-starter as admin I can see also "system properties" . 
Certainly if JDKs would be 32-bit and other 64-bit it would not work. been there.

I thought this notion needs to be added here.

Comment: Finally, when I started VisualVM under WIndows with admin rights, the error went away and I was able to see all details of my JVM process.

Answer (score 1):

My problem was JVM optimizations - `-XX:+PerfDisableSharedMem` flag will break VisualGC. This is apparent if jps will not show your app in the listing.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the application was running with admin permissions. So, visualVM also need to be running as admin.

Answer (score 0):

I have changed name to my Windows User and set it all lowercase, restarted my PC and it all works now.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the reason is that I have run the "jstatd" with a different user with the JVM process. I have a special user in the linux to start the JVM thread(it is a tomcat), but I start the jstatd process with root. If you use root to run jps, you cannot see any information of the JVM threads belonging to other users. That is the trouble.
I killed the "jstatd" process started by root, su to the owner of the JVM process, and restart the "jstatd" process and everything wokrs fine now.

Answer (score 0):

if VVM start with an error: Local Applications Cannot Be Monitored (Error Dialog On Startup) , it won't be able to profile!
https://visualvm.github.io/troubleshooting.html

Local Applications Cannot Be Monitored (Error Dialog On Startup)
Description: An error dialog saying that local applications cannot be monitored is shown immediately after VisualVM startup. Locally running Java applications are displayed as  (pid ###).

Resolution:  This can happen on Windows systems if the username contains capitalized letters. In this case, username is UserName but the jvmstat directory created by JDK is %TMP%\hsperfdata_username. To workaround the problem, exit all Java applications, delete the %TMP%\hsperfdata_username directory and create new %TMP%\hsperfdata_UserName directory.

Answer (score 0):

I had "Local Application" node which was not recognized even there were other Java processes using the same JRE version.
I'd recommend to cleanup VisualVM cache. This helped to me.
You can find cache folder once you open VisualVM node/process, in Overview section, for example:

```
Arguments: --branding visualvm --cachedir C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\VisualVM\Cache/2.1.7
```