# unable to display jstad monitoring in VisualVM tool

Tags: java, monitoring, visualvm, jstatd

I have EC2 instance hosting Tomcat application. It has JVM installed within.

I am trying to monitor VisualGC from my workstation.
In all those application instances we are able to establish the JMX connections in the visual vm tool, but for the plugin - Visual gc, for all the instances it says "Not supported for this JVM"

- we are able to connect to the instance by adding a JMX connection
- when I try to add jstatd connection, it displays "not supported for this JVM".

I have also created a policy file as suggested by other other solutions in the internet- 'jstatd.all.policy' and tried starting jstatd like below.
Command used -
`./jstatd -J-Djava.security.policy=jstatd.all.policy`

I made sure at that time jstatd was running in the instance, and we were able to get the stats in the instance in the command line, but We are somehow unable to get those stats displayed in the tool, the instance and visual gc plugin of the visual vm tool aren't connecting each other. Interestingly, we can see other monitor graphs.

Any reason out there why I am unble to view it?

I have already tried this command as well and this was it - `sudo ./jstatd -J-Djava.security.policy=/tmp/jstatd.all.policy -J-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=<host ip> -J-Djava.rmi.server.logCalls=true &`
but it did not solved the issue

Comment: can you check this link - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16233275/unable-to-view-visual-gc-in-visualvm

Comment: i have already worked through the solutions provided in the link, no success

Answer (score 0):

Hope your security policy file (tools.policy) missing permission for **tools.jar**

```
grant codebase “file:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/lib/tools.jar” {
 permission java.security.AllPermission;
};
```

Once added the above permission run jstatd,

```
sudo jstatd -J-Djava.security.policy=/tmp/tools.policy -J-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=10.101.32.110 -p 7198
```

Replace the JDK folder, hostname & port based on your env.

Comment: i have tried this as well and this was it - sudo ./jstatd -J-Djava.security.policy=/tmp/jstatd.all.policy -J-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=<host ip> -J-Djava.rmi.server.logCalls=true &