# No Visualgc plugin for java 8's Visualvm

Tags: java-8, visualvm

I want to use VisualVM to profile the gc of my Java 8 app but I can't find the visualgc plugin for java 8.

I have looked for it on google and in here:
https://visualvm.java.net/pluginscenters.html

But nothing....

This is the version of visualvm that came with my jdk:

```
Version:     
1.8.0_20 (Build 1370-140407); platform 20140407-unknown-revn    
System:     
Windows 7 (6.1) Service Pack 1, amd64 64bit    
Java:     
1.8.0_20; Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.20-b23, mixed mode)    
Vendor:     
Oracle Corporation, http://java.oracle.com/    
Environment:     
Cp1252; en_AU (visualvm)
```

Any clues to guide me in the right direction will be much appreciated.

Comment: I propose not to search websites. Just open the menu *within* JVisuaVM `Tools → Plugins` go to the “Available Plugins” tab, check “Visual GC” and click on “Install”. That’s how I did this with exactly this version (provided by jdk 1.8.0_20 64 Bit).

Comment: Try this link, https://stackoverflow.com/a/45817942/3876619 This will fix it.

Answer (score 1):

I downloaded 2.1.2 visualgc, thou' to find not supported still yet. Find that perm gen removed from jdk 8, which causes the plugin not to support.

Answer (score 0):

This was bug and it is fixed for version 2.1.2 (see https://java.net/jira/browse/VISUALVM-580)

I installed version 2.1.2 from http://www.netbeans.info/uc/show_uc_content.php?ucurl=http://bits.netbeans.org/VisualVM/uc/release137/updates.xml and it works.

Answer (score 0):

In Visual VM go to **Tools->Plugins->Available Plugins**
you will see a plugin with the name **Visual GC**. Install this plugin.
Restart your Visual VM. You will see Visual GC.

I just resolved using the above steps.